# Parse error: Unclosed '{' does not match ')'

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling, parse-error

Recently I get an error on one of my websites.
First it said the `{` wasn't supported, so i changed them to `[`
Now i get

> Parse error: Unclosed '{' does not match ')'

Anyone got an idea?

```
} elseif ( ! empty( $value ) && is_string( $value ) && (
        ( '[' == $value{0} && ']' == $value{strlen( $value ) - 1} ) ||
        ( '[' == $value{0} && ']' == $value{strlen( $value ) - 1} ) ||
```

Comment: I think the `{}` should be `[]` if your trying to access the string as an array.

Comment: @user3783243 - https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.deprecated.php#migration74.deprecated.core.array-string-access-curly-brace, although I would generally recommend sticking with `[]` as it's more consistent anyway.

Comment: What PHP version is being used? Looks like `{}` for array accessing was deprecated in PHP 7.4 and removed in 8. (@NigelRen Nevermind previous comment, figured it out)